# Parse query returns null if class has more than 3 rows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have the following query and if I have more than 3 rows in my class `("vendasRelatorio")` the query returns null. If I have 3 or less rows it works fine.
Here's my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryR = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("vendasRelatorio");
            queryR.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if(e==null){
                        System.out.println("SUCCESS" + list);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("ERROR " + list);
                    }

                }
            });
```

UPDATE:
This is the exception I get if my class has more than 3 rows: `com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure`

Comment: What does your code print? Please update question to show what you actually see.

Comment: This is what happens if I have only three rows on the database`SUCCESS[com.parse.ParseObject@21125970, com.parse.ParseObject@21126280, com.parse.ParseObject@21126b48]`
And this is what happes if I have more than 3:
`ERROR null`

Comment: As I said, please **update question** (by clicking the `edit` link). --- So, you have an error, indicated by receiving a non-null `ParseException`. Perhaps actually printing the error message, i.e. the exception, would be helpful to figure out what went wrong, instead of just saying "Something failed, but I won't tell you what".

Comment: Ok, I updated the question. @Andreas

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges pl check if list is null or not then put to print log.